# Extract vacant time between two time ranges in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need help! I have a problem with this kind of logic for my scheduling app. Given a time between 8AM to 12PM, and there's a schedule set for 9AM-10AM, how can I extract the vacant time which are 8AM-9AM and 10AM-12PM ?

Here's the code:

```
class VacantTimeFinder
  def initialize(args={})
    @schedules = args[:schedules]
    @eight_am = DateTime.new(2000,1,1,8,0,0,DateTime.now.zone)
    @twelve_pm = DateTime.new(2000,1,1,12,0,0,DateTime.now.zone)
  end

  def find!
    vacant_times = []
    @schedules.each do |schedule|
      starts_at = schedule.starts_at
      ends_at   = schedule.ends_at
      if (starts_at..ends_at).overlaps?(@eight_am..@twelve_am)
        #logic goes here...
      end
    end
    vacant_times #formated as ["8AM - 9AM", "10AM - 12PM"]
  end
end
```

Or any other solutions will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
result = []
e = @eight
schedules.sort.each do |s|
  result << [e, s.start]
  e = s.end
end
result << [e, @twelve]
result
```